# in need to perform the output from XML input and XSL to create the XML output

Tags: xml, xslt

i had written the following xml code that will be the input and with going to the xslt script which will handle the xml code to generate the xml output:

**XML input**

```
<TAB512>
<WA>f1,f2</WA>
</TAB512>
<TAB512>
<WA>df1,df2</WA>
</TAB512>
</DATA>
<FIELDS>
<Filed>
<FIELDNAME>Field1</FIELDNAME>
</Filed>
<Filed>
<FIELDNAME>Field2</FIELDNAME>
</Filed>
</FIELDS>
</Response>
```

First element in the `<WA>` for the First element in the `<FIELDNAME>`
the xsl script will format the input xml to generate the xml output

```
<TAB512>
<WA>f1,f2</WA>
</TAB512>
```

i mean that the first element before ',' that will be for the Field1 and the element after ',' for the Field2

**XSL script**

```
    <xsl:template name="WriteRecordNodeTemplate">
<xsl:param name="Field" />
<xsl:param name="WA" />

<Response>
<xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">
<xsl:with-param name="fi" select="$Field" />
<xsl:with-param name="w" select="$WA" />
</xsl:call-template>
</Response>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="StringSplit">
<xsl:param name="fi" />
<xsl:param name="w" />
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($w, ',')">
<Record>
   <xsl:value-of select="$fi" ><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($w, ',')" /></xsl:value-of select="$fi" >
</Record>

     <xsl:call-template name="StringSplit">
     <xsl:param name="fi" />
     <xsl:with-param name="w" select="substring-after($w, ',')" />
     </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- if there is no more delimiter values, print out 
the whole string -->
<Record>
<xsl:value-of select="$fi" ><xsl:value-of select="$w" /></xsl:value-of select="$fi" >
</Record>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Finally

**Need XML Output like this:**

```
<TableName>
<Record>
<Field1>f1</Field1>
<Field2>f2</Field2>
</Record>
<Record>
<Field1>df1</Field1>
<Field2>df2</Field2>
</Record>
</TableName>
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of the required transformation - esp. what links between the field names and the data, and what determines how many records the output should have. Having different data for each field would also help to make the example clearer.  -- Also please state if you can use XSLT 2.0 or not.

Comment: first WA element in the Data = first Field Name

Comment: i need to use it in a biztalk script functoid  using inline xslt call template

Comment: Still not clear. Please change your example so it has at least 3 records, and use different data for each cell.

Comment: it's okay will edit it now

Comment: I only see 2 records . And I see that "f2" is in Field2 - which contradicts what you said earlier: "*first WA element in the Data = first Field Name*".

Comment: <TAB512>
<WA>f1,f2</WA>
</TAB512>
i mean that the first element before ',' that will be for the Field1 and the element after ',' for the Field2

Comment: The word `element` has a very specific meaning in XML. What you refer to could be called a substring, a token, a value ... but not element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="field-names" select="/Response/FIELDS/Filed" />

<xsl:template match="/Response">
    <TableName>
        <xsl:for-each select="DATA/TAB512">
            <Record>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="WA"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </TableName>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{$field-names[$i]/FIELDNAME}">
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following test input:

**XMl**

```
<Response>
  <DATA>
    <TAB512>
      <WA>a1,b1</WA>
    </TAB512>
    <TAB512>
      <WA>a2,b2</WA>
    </TAB512>
  </DATA>
  <FIELDS>
    <Filed>
      <FIELDNAME>ColumnA</FIELDNAME>
    </Filed>
    <Filed>
      <FIELDNAME>ColumnB</FIELDNAME>
    </Filed>
  </FIELDS>
</Response>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableName>
   <Record>
      <ColumnA>a1</ColumnA>
      <ColumnB>b1</ColumnB>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <ColumnA>a2</ColumnA>
      <ColumnB>b2</ColumnB>
   </Record>
</TableName>
```

---

Note that this requires `FIELDNAME` values to be valid XML names. It also assumes that each `WA` element has the same number of comma-separated values as the number of `Filed` nodes.

It is also assumed that your input misspells `Filed` as shown in your example.

Comment: Thank You so much , you're amazing